# Do doc hyperlinks not work in the Word WebApp in Chrome?

Tags: document-library, document, hyperlink, chrome

I have been adding Word documents to my document library in SharePoint and I only recently became aware that hyperlinks don't seem to work when I preview documents in the Word WebApp using Chrome. Is this a known issue I should be aware of, and if so is there a solution other than forcing all users to either download the documents or use IE/Edge?

**Edit**

I've messed around a bit and learned some things. A hyperlink *will* work in Chrome so long as it is on the first page of the document and is at least three paragraph spaces from the bottom of the page. So they can work, but not in any sort of helpful way since my documents have a cover page.

Still looking for a definitive answer or solution though. I don't want to waste a lot of time only to learn that this is a known issue with no solution.

**Edit 2**

I installed the IETab extension for Chrome. Using that to view SharePoint pages allows links in documents to function properly. However, I still need to know why hyperlinks in Word documents don't work in Chrome and if this can be fixed in any way. Most of the  people who use SharePoint at my company work exclusively in Chrome and it will be difficult to force all of them to switch to Edge or IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I have found is that Chrome prevents hyperlinks from working in the Word web app unless you have the IETab extension installed in Chrome (and you are using it).