# Issue with hyperlinks with Office Web App Previews in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: document, hyperlink, owa, preview

I have a powerpoint file in my SharePoint 2013 site which has hyperlinks in it. I am able to see the powerpoint preview in OWA (Office Web Apps).

However when I click the hyperlink in the OWA preview pane, the tab is opening and closing immediately, this is happening in both Chrome & Firefox browsers (latest versions). Surprisingly Internet Explorer 11 (IE 11) is working fine without any issue.

The hyperlinks are not relative links, they are full hyperlinks to other files within the same sharepoint site. When I type-in (or copy) the same link manually, it is working fine even in chrome & firefox browsers.

For me it seems, there seems to be some issue with the OWA and hyperlinks in document previews. But I am not able to fully understand the exact cause and resolution. Anyone please help me.

Regards,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with hyperlinks in the SharePoint web apps ([see this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176614/do-doc-hyperlinks-not-work-in-the-word-webapp-in-chrome)). I believe that there is just an incompatibility with viewing/using hyperlinks in the web app previews in browsers other than IE or Edge. So far haven't found a resolution of the root problem, but if you download the IE Tab add-on for Chrome or Firefox then you can use that when working in a web app and the links should work correctly. It sucks, but it's the only option I have found to make the links work correctly outside of IE.